# log4j2 health info and error handling

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I have a SpringBoot application which uses log4j2 logger. What i'm trying to do is get some "health" information from the logger, like: Can it log the next line or is enough space left? is it operating correctly? I thing log4j2 does this checks but i cant find where. I know log4j2 has his own error handling via FailOver appender, but i want to implement my own error handlers. Like when
disk is full and cant log any more lines, shutdown the application.

So what i need some pre checks before the log events, and if logger does these checks by itself i need those informations

Answer (score 1):

The standard appenders in log4j2 do not perform checks before writing. They would be expensive and still wouldn’t guarantee the log record could be written

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ralph’s answer, Log4j2 is designed as an audit logging framework.  This means that if logging is critical to your application, such that the application should fail if logging failed, Log4j2 can accomplish this.

All built-in [appenders](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender) have a configuration attribute `ignoreExceptions` for this purpose. From the manual:

> The default is `true`, causing exceptions encountered while appending events to be internally logged and then ignored. When set to `false` exceptions will be propagated to the caller, instead.